# ngx-translate this.translate.onLangChange is not working during route change

Tags: angular-router, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate in my angular app. And I am dynamically changing array value to key and dynamically getting translation value from es.josn file. It was working fine when app was first time loaded. But the problem is when I am changing route and get back to this route again then 
following was working fine means I am getting  data.

```
this.assetOnboardingService.getAssetType().subscribe(
      (data) => {

});
```

but following was not working which is inside of the subscription, means translate.onLangChange is not triggering any event :

```
 this.langChange = this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event:LangChangeEvent) => {
 let avilableaAssetType:AssetType[] = [];
            if (data) {
              data.forEach(assettype => {
                let model = new AssetType(assettype.name, assettype.status);
                avilableaAssetType.push(model);
              });
            }
            avilableaAssetType.forEach(data => {
              let name=this.sentenceToKey(data.name);
              this.translate.get(name).subscribe(res => {
                this.avilableaAssetType.push({
                  name: res,
                  status:data.status});

              });

            });

          });
```

the full code is in here:

```
 this.assetOnboardingService.getAssetType().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log("after route chnage it is working");

this.langChange = this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event:LangChangeEvent) => {
           console.log("after route chnage it is NOT working");


            let avilableaAssetType:AssetType[] = [];
            if (data) {
              data.forEach(assettype => {
                let model = new AssetType(assettype.name, assettype.status);
                avilableaAssetType.push(model);
              });
            }
            avilableaAssetType.forEach(data => {
              let name=this.sentenceToKey(data.name);
              this.translate.get(name).subscribe(res => {
                this.avilableaAssetType.push({
                  name: res,
                  status:data.status});

              });

            });

          });



      }
    );
```